# Update root crontab with Ansible

Tags: ansible, cron

I have the following Ansible task:

```
    - name: foo
      ansible.builtin.cron:
        name: "bar"
        minute: "*/5"
        job: " /home/mytask.sh"
        user: root
```

The goal is to update root's crontab (similiar to `sudo crontab -e`). However I get the following error:

```
fatal: [192.168.1.11]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "must be privileged to use -u\n"}
```

Usually, in Ansible, the option `become: true` is used to perform task as root, but the `cron` module does not support it. How could I modify my task accordingly to my needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`become: true` is a task/play/inventory level option not a module option. At task level for example you can use:

```yaml
    - name: foo
      ansible.builtin.cron:
        name: "bar"
        minute: "*/5"
        job: " /home/mytask.sh"
        user: root
      become: true
```

See [ansible privilege escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html)